# What is the best way to center images which have been appended through javascript?

Tags: css, image

So I've got 3 Images which appear when a button is clicked (each have their own button).
At the moment these images are stacked next to eachother left to right and have a bit of css styling done individually but I want to have these images presented in a typical photo gallery way. But I'm not sure how to do this when everything in relation to the images (the class, Id, src etc) is created via javascript.

I tried to create a typical Parent and child div as if I were creating a photo gallery using the class names I created within javascript but I couldn't seem to get that to work. The images dissapear completely when the classess created within html are active(*I'm not referring to the css active btw*).

CSS

```
    .images{
        text-align:center;

        border:3px solid #666;
    }

    .characterImg, .featureImg, .traitImg{
        display:inline-block;

        border:1px solid #CCC;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div class = "images" id = "images">
    <div class = "characterImg" id="characterImg"></div>
    <div class = "featureImg" id="featureImg"></div>
    <div class = "traitImg" id="traitImg"></div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    //before button clicked

    //this code is repeated three times for each image
    {
    let characterImage = document.createElement("IMG");
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(characterImage);
    characterImage.id = "characterImg";
    characterImage.className = "characterImg";
    characterImage.src = "Placeholder";
    characterImage.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    //When button clicked
    function buttonAreaOne(){
    document.getElementById("characterImg").src="Game Photos/Henry";                         
    document.getElementById("characterImg").style.visibility = "visible";
    }




I just want these images centered with a border around them
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're currently getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error as such it's just my images completely disappear whenever the html classess are active.

Comment: I understand, could you post a screenshot of the page.

Comment: They disappear maybe because visibility is set as hidden

Comment: I just need to see what it looks like first, as you're talking about buttons but I don't see any in your `HTML`.

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary as the button is just <button onclick="buttonAreaOne()">Henry Button</button>. Would you be interested if I perhaps uploaded the whole thing to github or something?